# ¿Cómo pongo hacia abajo un elemento de la página web?

Tags: html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me queda así y lo que quiero es que la tabla se quede abajo y centrada como la puse en el css

```css
body { background-color:LIGHTGOLDENRODYELLOW;
}
#principal {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
}

#principal > div {
width: 33%;
}

#columna1 {
color: green;

}

#columna2 {
color: red;
word-break: break-all;
}

#columna3 {
color: grey;
}

h1 {color: purple;
text-align:center;
}

h4 { color: blue;

}
span {
color: royalblue;
}
img {
float: left;

}

a.enlacenav { text-decoration: none; } 
  a:link.enlacenav { color: purple; } 
  a:hover.enlacenav { color: green; letter-spacing:3px; }
  a:active.enlacenav { color:white; text-decoration: underline; } 
  a:visited.enlacenav { color:purple; } 
  
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
}
.a {
color: yellow;
background-color:green;
}
.e {
color: yellow;
background-color: darkred;
}

caption {
color: purple;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">


<head>
<title>La trilogia del señor de los anillos</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/estilos.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div>
<h1> La trilogía del señor de los anillos</h1>
<p>El Señor de los Anillos (título original en inglés: The Lord of the Rings) es una novela de fantasía épica 
escrita por el filólogo y escritor británico J. R. R. Tolkien.
Su historia se desarrolla en la Tercera Edad del Sol de la Tierra Media, un lugar ficticio poblado por hombres y otras razas  
antropomorfas como los hobbits, los elfos o los enanos, así como por muchas otras criaturas reales y fantásticas. 
La novela narra el viaje del protagonista principal, el hobbit Frodo Bolsón, para destruir el Anillo Único 
y la consiguiente guerra que provocará el enemigo para recuperarlo, ya que es la principal fuente de poder de su creador, el Señor oscuro Sauron.</p>
</div>


<div id="principal">
 
<div id="columna1"><h4>El señor de los anillos: La comunidad del anillo</h4>Año 2001<br>
Director: Peter jackson<br>
Web oficial: <a href="http://lordoftherings.net" class="enlacenav" target="_blank">http://lordoftherings.net</a><br><br>
<img src="C:\Users\uno\Pictures\142154fcb523f8727db041bafeb7fb746fbeb68e_full.jpg" alt="venom">
<p>En la Tierra Media, el Señor Oscuro Saurón ordenó a los Elfos que forjaran los Grandes Anillos de Poder. 
Tres para los reyes Elfos, siete para los Señores Enanos, y nueve para los Hombres Mortales. 
Pero Saurón también forjó, en secreto, el Anillo Único, que tiene el poder de esclavizar toda la Tierra Media. 
Con la ayuda de sus amigos y de valientes aliados, el joven hobbit Frodo emprende un peligroso viaje 
con la misión de destruir el Anillo Único. Pero el malvado Sauron ordena la persecución del grupo, 
compuesto por Frodo y sus leales amigos hobbits, un mago, un hombre, un elfo y un enano. 
La misión es casi suicida pero necesaria, 
pues si Sauron con su ejército de orcos lograra recuperar el Anillo, sería el final de la Tierra Media.</p></div>

<div id="columna2"><h4>El señor de los anillos: La comunidad del anillo</h4>Año 2001<br>
Director: Peter jackson<br>
Web oficial: <a href="http://lordoftherings.net" class="enlacenav" target="_blank">http://lordoftherings.net</a><br><br>
<img class="alineado" src="C:\Users\uno\Pictures\142154fcb523f8727db041bafeb7fb746fbeb68e_full.jpg" alt="venom">Tras la disolución de la Compañía del Anillo, Frodo y su fiel amigo Sam se dirigen hacia Mordor 
para destruir el Anillo Único y acabar con el poder de Sauron. Mientras, y tras la dura batalla contra los orcos 
donde cayó Boromir, el hombre Aragorn, el elfo Legolas y el enano Gimli intentan rescatar a los medianos Merry y Pipin, 
secuestrados por los orcos de Mordor. Por su parte, Saurón y el traidor Sarumán continúan con sus planes en Mordor, 
a la espera de la guerra contra las razas libres de la Tierra Media.
</div>
<div id="columna3"><h4>El señor de los anillos: El retorno del rey</h4>Año 2001<br>
Director: Peter jackson<br>
Web oficial: <a href="http://lordoftherings.net" class="enlacenav" target="_blank">http://lordoftherings.net</a><br><br>
<img src="C:\Users\uno\Pictures\142154fcb523f8727db041bafeb7fb746fbeb68e_full.jpg" alt="venom">Las fuerzas de Saruman han sido destruidas, y su fortaleza sitiada. 
Ha llegado el momento de decidir el destino de la Tierra Media, y, por primera vez, parece que hay una pequeña esperanza. 
El interés del señor oscuro Sauron se centra ahora en Gondor, el último reducto de los hombres, 
cuyo trono será reclamado por Aragorn. Sauron se dispone a lanzar un ataque decisivo contra Gondor. 
Mientras tanto, Frodo y Sam continuan su camino hacia Mordor, con la esperanza de llegar al Monte del Destino.
</div>

<div>
<table>
 <caption>Premios obtenidos</caption>
  <tr>
   <th rowspan="2">Premios</th>
   <th rowspan="2">Categoría</th>
   <th colspan="3">Resultado</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <th class="a">La comunidad del anillo</th>
   <th class="a">Las dos torres</th>
   <th class="a">El Retorno del Rey</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <th rowspan="5"><p>Oscar</p> <img src="C:/Users\uno/Desktop/Martin_Adrián\img/globos.jpg" alt="oscar"/></th>
   <td>Mejor película</td>
   <td>Nominación</td>
   <td></td>
   <td class="e">Ganador</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Mejor director</td>
   <td>Nominación</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>Nominación</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Mejor guión</td>
   <td>Nominación</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>Nominación</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Mejor guión</td>
   <td>Nominación</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>Nominación</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Mejor guión</td>
   <td>Nominación</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>Nominación</td>
   </tr>
   </table>
</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Abajo y centrada? ¿en qué eje?

Comment: asi https://imgur.com/NoJkLb9

Answer (score 0):

Solo debes sacar tu tabla del div "principal" para que no le afecte `display: flex;` y se comporte como un bloque `display: block;`. Saludos!

```css
body { background-color:LIGHTGOLDENRODYELLOW;
}
#principal {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
}

#principal > div {
width: 33%;
}

#columna1 {
color: green;

}

#columna2 {
color: red;
word-break: break-all;
}

#columna3 {
color: grey;
}

h1 {color: purple;
text-align:center;
}

h4 { color: blue;

}
span {
color: royalblue;
}
img {
float: left;

}

a.enlacenav { text-decoration: none; } 
  a:link.enlacenav { color: purple; } 
  a:hover.enlacenav { color: green; letter-spacing:3px; }
  a:active.enlacenav { color:white; text-decoration: underline; } 
  a:visited.enlacenav { color:purple; } 


  
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
}
.a {
color: yellow;
background-color:green;
}
.e {
color: yellow;
background-color: darkred;
}

caption {
color: purple;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">


<head>
<title>La trilogia del señor de los anillos</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/estilos.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div>
<h1> La trilogía del señor de los anillos</h1>
<p>El Señor de los Anillos (título original en inglés: The Lord of the Rings) es una novela de fantasía épica 
escrita por el filólogo y escritor británico J. R. R. Tolkien.
Su historia se desarrolla en la Tercera Edad del Sol de la Tierra Media, un lugar ficticio poblado por hombres y otras razas  
antropomorfas como los hobbits, los elfos o los enanos, así como por muchas otras criaturas reales y fantásticas. 
La novela narra el viaje del protagonista principal, el hobbit Frodo Bolsón, para destruir el Anillo Único 
y la consiguiente guerra que provocará el enemigo para recuperarlo, ya que es la principal fuente de poder de su creador, el Señor oscuro Sauron.</p>
</div>


<div id="principal">
 
<div id="columna1"><h4>El señor de los anillos: La comunidad del anillo</h4>Año 2001<br>
Director: Peter jackson<br>
Web oficial: <a href="http://lordoftherings.net" class="enlacenav" target="_blank">http://lordoftherings.net</a><br><br>
<img src="C:\Users\uno\Pictures\142154fcb523f8727db041bafeb7fb746fbeb68e_full.jpg" alt="venom">
<p>En la Tierra Media, el Señor Oscuro Saurón ordenó a los Elfos que forjaran los Grandes Anillos de Poder. 
Tres para los reyes Elfos, siete para los Señores Enanos, y nueve para los Hombres Mortales. 
Pero Saurón también forjó, en secreto, el Anillo Único, que tiene el poder de esclavizar toda la Tierra Media. 
Con la ayuda de sus amigos y de valientes aliados, el joven hobbit Frodo emprende un peligroso viaje 
con la misión de destruir el Anillo Único. Pero el malvado Sauron ordena la persecución del grupo, 
compuesto por Frodo y sus leales amigos hobbits, un mago, un hombre, un elfo y un enano. 
La misión es casi suicida pero necesaria, 
pues si Sauron con su ejército de orcos lograra recuperar el Anillo, sería el final de la Tierra Media.</p></div>

<div id="columna2"><h4>El señor de los anillos: La comunidad del anillo</h4>Año 2001<br>
Director: Peter jackson<br>
Web oficial: <a href="http://lordoftherings.net" class="enlacenav" target="_blank">http://lordoftherings.net</a><br><br>
<img class="alineado" src="C:\Users\uno\Pictures\142154fcb523f8727db041bafeb7fb746fbeb68e_full.jpg" alt="venom">Tras la disolución de la Compañía del Anillo, Frodo y su fiel amigo Sam se dirigen hacia Mordor 
para destruir el Anillo Único y acabar con el poder de Sauron. Mientras, y tras la dura batalla contra los orcos 
donde cayó Boromir, el hombre Aragorn, el elfo Legolas y el enano Gimli intentan rescatar a los medianos Merry y Pipin, 
secuestrados por los orcos de Mordor. Por su parte, Saurón y el traidor Sarumán continúan con sus planes en Mordor, 
a la espera de la guerra contra las razas libres de la Tierra Media.
</div>
<div id="columna3"><h4>El señor de los anillos: El retorno del rey</h4>Año 2001<br>
Director: Peter jackson<br>
Web oficial: <a href="http://lordoftherings.net" class="enlacenav" target="_blank">http://lordoftherings.net</a><br><br>
<img src="C:\Users\uno\Pictures\142154fcb523f8727db041bafeb7fb746fbeb68e_full.jpg" alt="venom">Las fuerzas de Saruman han sido destruidas, y su fortaleza sitiada. 
Ha llegado el momento de decidir el destino de la Tierra Media, y, por primera vez, parece que hay una pequeña esperanza. 
El interés del señor oscuro Sauron se centra ahora en Gondor, el último reducto de los hombres, 
cuyo trono será reclamado por Aragorn. Sauron se dispone a lanzar un ataque decisivo contra Gondor. 
Mientras tanto, Frodo y Sam continuan su camino hacia Mordor, con la esperanza de llegar al Monte del Destino.
</div>
</div>
<div id="tableContainer">
<table>
 <caption>Premios obtenidos</caption>
  <tr>
   <th rowspan="2">Premios</th>
   <th rowspan="2">Categoría</th>
   <th colspan="3">Resultado</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <th class="a">La comunidad del anillo</th>
   <th class="a">Las dos torres</th>
   <th class="a">El Retorno del Rey</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <th rowspan="5"><p>Oscar</p> <img src="C:/Users\uno/Desktop/Martin_Adrián\img/globos.jpg" alt="oscar"/></th>
   <td>Mejor película</td>
   <td>Nominación</td>
   <td></td>
   <td class="e">Ganador</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Mejor director</td>
   <td>Nominación</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>Nominación</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Mejor guión</td>
   <td>Nominación</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>Nominación</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Mejor guión</td>
   <td>Nominación</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>Nominación</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Mejor guión</td>
   <td>Nominación</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>Nominación</td>
   </tr>
   </table>
   
</body>
</html>
```